# How to get all member birthday date in one line code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, variables

I have created variable but getting confused how to get date of birth in year of each member like : member1Age (26);

```
let currentYear, member1Age, member2Age, member3Age, member4Age, member5Age;
currentYear = 2019;
member1Age = 1993;
member2Age = 1994;
member3Age = 1975;
member4Age = 1970;
member5Age = 1995;
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this? Not taking into account if your birthday is before or after today

```js
const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
console.log(
  [1993,
    1994,
    1975,
    1970,
    1995
  ].map(yyyy => currentYear - yyyy)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to calculate age dependant on birth year?
If so, that's as simple as taking the current year minus the birth year:

```
getAge(birthYear) {
    var thisYear = new Date().getFullYear()
    return thisYear - birthYear;
}
```

And used like this:

```
var age = getYear(member1Age);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead for making that many variables you can go with an Array of objects, Like this:

```
memberAge = [{name:foo , Dob:1993} , {name:bar , Dob:2000}];
```

and then you can use the map() on this array "memberAge" Like this:

```
memberAge.map((eachMember)=>{...});
```

map() will take each object one by one and you can perform whatever you want to do with that single object

inside you can console.log or make different variable for age

logic is pretty simple

```
Age=currentDate-Dob;
```